# How to open the java file instead of JMX file in JMeter tool?

Tags: jmeter

While saving a Load test in JMeter , it got saved with an extension .JMX. When I try to open it in Notepad it displayed in "XML" structure. What I want is "Java Source Code" for a particular load test.

In which path is that java file stored?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you read the jmeter getting started guide? Jmeter GUI saves its test plan files as an xml file with jmx extension. There is no source code. see: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-test-plan.html

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter saves test plan as xml, not java.

There is no way currently to do what you want.

Comment: Tank u....
In Non-GUI Mode file will be in .Java format only. I'm little confussed with the GUI-Mode

Comment: hi, First note if answer is ok it should be accepted and upvoted. regarding your question I don't understand it. There is no java format saved in jmeter (gui or non-gui)